# Android, Realm, Kotlin check RealmObject has field matching variable, set RealmObject key with variable

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

So I have booleans in SharedPreferences in Android.

I want to conditionally update the booleans in my Realm instance in the onPreferenceChanged listener. Some of the booleans are matched in the Realm Object, some are not.

I would like to be able to see if the RealmObject has a key that matches the Preference Key and if so update the RealmObject with the Preference value.

Here's the code

```
private val booleanBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, value ->

    //log the preference change
    Log.d(TAG, "onBooleanPreferenceChanged: ${preference.key}: $value")
    //open the instance of Realm so we can update changes to the user object and have the information on the server
    val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    //get the userID from globals
    val userID = Globals.read("UserID", "")
    //make sure that the User ID is not null or blank
    if (!userID.isNullOrBlank()){
       //query the Realm database to get our instance of the user
       val user = realm.where<User>().equalTo("platformUserID", userID).findFirst()!!
       //find out if this particular boolean value is saved to the Realm object    

       //TO DO

    }
    realm.close()
    true

}
```

In JavaScript I would just list the object keys and filter the array for any matches, then I would be able to write something like

> if (matches.some === true) User[preference.key] = preference.value

I'm new to Kotlin but I thought this should be easy. It's eluding me at the moment.